# pandas.dataFrame. Рассчитать данные произвольным образом из численного столбца произвольного размера

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, std

Опыт в программировании не один год, но это мой первый пост на SOF. Прошу помочь мне на позитивной волне влиться в изучение python ☺.

Дано:

- [dataFrame pandas c колонкой bid, содержащей float64 (курс валюты)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CsY8DjrU2eQ6slh5wfGdMl3ARkWd1sDt#scrollTo=gUelwNCFRmjN&line=17&uniqifier=1)

Найти:

- Для значения колонки std в каждой строке N датафрейма найти среднеквадратческое отклонение на основании предыдущих i=2 значений (N-1 и N-2; два - в качестве примера; в работе будет i=1000-100000) из колонки bid чтобы получилось как в последней ячейке по ссылке из Дано (и так для 50 миллионов строк - поэтому ищу способы сделать это оптимально)
- (опционально) Универсальный алгоритм, который мог бы считать не только std, но и, скажем, среднекубическое отклонение (только что придумал), то есть, в широком смылсе - взять f(∑X(i)) произвольную функцию от i предыдущих значений колонки

Решение:

- apply не подходит т.к. берет общее значение std по всей колонке bid
- rolling не взлетел т.к. нет процедуры вычисления std для каждой строки, а numpy не принимает на вход данные сложного типа, только массив чисел
- циклом делать не хочется, т.к. предполагаю что для 50 миллионов строк это затянется надолго, но если это единственный вариант - он принимается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*rolling не взлетел т.к. нет процедуры вычисления std для каждой строки,*  - объясните, что вы имели ввиду, когда писали. Дело в том,

```
что df['B']=df.A.rolling(window=N).std()
```

прекрасно считает std на основании последних N значений столбца A и записывает результат в столбец B.

Непонятно и выражение *"а numpy не принимает на вход данные сложного типа, только массив чисел"*  -  а откуда у вас в bid данные "сложного типа"?

Ну и наконец:
*Универсальный алгоритм,....взять ... произвольную функцию от i предыдущих значений колонки*

```
def my_func(r): 
    s=r.iloc[0]**0+r.iloc[1]**1+r.iloc[2]**2+r.iloc[3]**3
    return (s)
df['C']=df['A'].rolling(window=4, axis='rows').apply(lambda row: my_func(row))
```

Comment: 1. rolling - по какой то причине меня не устроил результат ф-ии, скорее всего не указал window, сейчас понимаю что все ок

2. numpy - не удалось выгрузить в него массив из rolling, numpy ругался что данные типа объект не поддерживаются, этот вопрос закрыт

3. универсальный алгоритм - + спасибо